# Pass a variable to a observable

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm currently using an observable in the following way:

```
this._socket.onMessage.subscribe(
    (message) => {

    }
);
```

which works fine! However, Would it be possible to pass a variable to the observable that would allow for some logic?

For example by passing a variable "name" to onMessage, I could subscribe only to events whos name is something specific? Like this:

```
this._socket.onMessage(name-variable).subscribe(
    (message) => {
        // only get events that is related to the name-variable
    }
);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to create helper functions that yield the desired effect.

```
public getMessagesForName(name: string): Observable<any> {
    return this._socket.onMessage.filter((message) => {
        return message.name === name;
    });
}
```

The more advanced approach would be to create your own class that extends one of the `Subject` classes. Like `EventEmitter` or `Subject` and add the helper functions there. You would then just apply the filter to the `this` reference.

Here's an example:

```
 class MessageEvent extends EventEmitter<MessageData> {
       public forName(name: string): Observable<MessageData> {
          return this.filter((message) => {
               return message.name === name;
          });
       }
 }
```

It all depends on how much re-use you need.

Comment: Exactly what I need. Will work this in and reward accordingly. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Edit: See the answer by ThnkingMedia

I'm not so sure if you can do it with the syntax you're looking for, but you could probably do something along the lines of

```
let flag: boolean = someProperty;
this._socket.onMessage.subscribe(
    (message) => {
        if (flag) { // do something
        }
    }
);
```

Also, I'm pretty sure on your Observable you can use a filter() call. So the Observable could probably change

```
myObservable.filter(...).map(...).subscribe(....)
//where myObservable is the Observable object you're working with
```

Answer (score 3):

For anybody needing this, this is how you can pass variables to observables and use the observer at the same time:

```
function onMessage(message): Observable<any>{
   return new Observable(observer => {
      socket.message(message).subscribe(result => {
         observer.next(result); 
      });
   });
}
```

This way you can use it like this:

```
onMessage('Hello World').subscribe(msg => {
   alert(msg);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite understand what you meant here, but yes you can pass a value to an Observable. The code is quite simple

```
returnCustomObservable() {
    return Observable.of('Your value here');
}
```

However, if I got you correctly, this means you have to rewrite the `onMessage` function to give it the value you want.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I believe that is the answer I'm looking for, quite straight forward. I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that with a small design shift:

```
function handleFoo(data) {}

function handleBar(data) {}

const messageGroups = {
  foo: handleFoo
  bar: handleBar
}

this._socket.onMessage.subscribe(
    (message) => messageGroups[message.type](message)
);
```

this will allow more generic handling of specific message groups, which imo, is a cleaner way to achieve MDNs suggestion: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications#Receiving_messages_from_the_server